# iOS file formats registration so the Quick Look preview is skipped

Tags: ios, quicklook

Is it possible to register a file format in iOS so that the Quick Look preview is skipped? I'm asking for a binary file format which iOS doesn't support and Quick Look shows just the useless text representation.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: No, but it seems the behavior changed with the iOS version and in my case it no longer tried to display it.